# Error in 'return' statement in function which is supposed to return the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have written a function which is supposed to return the dataframe according to the condition satisfies. For this condition, I wrote if else function.

```
def performPCA(inputFileName):
    
    global df_1_withPCA, df_2_withPCA

    pca = PCA()

    pca.fit(inputFileName)     

    pca_scores = pca.transform(inputFileName)

    if str(1) in str(inputFileName):
        df_1_withPCA = pd.DataFrame(pca_scores)

        # Add columns names 
        df_1_withPCA = df_1_withPCA.set_axis(['X_coordinate', 'Y_coordinate', 'Z_coordinate'], axis=1)

        # Round to two decimals
        df_1_withPCA = df_1_withPCA.round(2)

        # Print scores
        df_1_withPCA                                 

        return df_1_withPCA
    
    else :
        df_2_withPCA = pd.DataFrame(pca_scores)

        # Add columns names 
        df_2_withPCA = df_2_withPCA.set_axis(['X_coordinate', 'Y_coordinate', 'Z_coordinate'], axis=1)

        # Round to two decimals
        df_2_withPCA = df_2_withPCA.round(2)

        # Print scores
        df_2_withPCA                                 # These are the same values that we calculated by hand
        
        return df_2_withPCA
```

The data which I want to input is

```
df_1_centered

X_coordinate    Y_coordinate    Z_coordinate
     0.546923    2.088462       -0.5
    -0.043077    0.798462       -0.5
    -0.643077   -0.481538       -0.5
     0.896923    1.148462       -0.5



df_2_centered

X_coordinate    Y_coordinate    Z_coordinate
    -1.769231   -1.230769       -0.5
    -1.769231   -0.230769       -0.5
    -0.769231   -0.230769       -0.5
    -0.769231    0.769231       -0.5
```

When I write `performPCA(df_1_centered)`, my function returns `df_1_withPCA`. However, when I write `performPCA(df_2_centered)`, my function does not return the dataframe `df_2_withPCA` which I expect to get it.

Error I get:

```
NameError: name 'df_2_withPCA' is not defined
```

Kindly let me know where I should do a change.

Answer (score 0):

It returns for me fine:

```
df_2_centered = pd.DataFrame({'X_coordinate': [0, 0, 0, 0]})
df_2_centered['X_coordinate'] = [-1.769231, -1.769231, -0.769231 , -0.769231]
df_2_centered['Y_coordinate'] = [-1.230769, -0.230769, -0.230769, 0.769231]
df_2_centered['Z_coordinate'] = [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 ]
```

I get the output:

```
X_coordinate  Y_coordinate  Z_coordinate
0          1.11          0.10           0.0
1          0.26         -0.43           0.0
2         -0.26          0.43           0.0
3         -1.11         -0.10           0.0
```